# yq replace all values in a list with decoded version of itself

Tags: yaml, yq

I have some yaml as below:

```yaml
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.1
  critical: false
  value: aHR0cHM6Ly90b2tlbi5hY3Rpb25zLmdpdGh1YnVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbQ==
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.2
  critical: false
  value: c2NoZWR1bGU=
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.3
  critical: false
  value: NDFkZjA0YjFkZmYzNDQ5MGRiNTg0NDk1ZjZiOTE2YWQxYjBlOGY2ZA==
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.4
  critical: false
  value: Q3JlYXRlIFJlbGVhc2U=
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.5
  critical: false
  value: Y2hhaW5ndWFyZC1pbWFnZXMvYWxwaW5lLWJhc2U=
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.6
  critical: false
  value: cmVmcy9oZWFkcy9tYWlu
```

How can I use yq to replace the `value: <base64_string>` with it's decoded value?

The desired output would be:

```yaml
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.1
  critical: false
  value: https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.2
  critical: false
  value: schedule
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.3
  critical: false
  value: 41df04b1dff34490db584495f6b916ad1b0e8f6d
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.4
  critical: false
  value: Create Release
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.5
  critical: false
  value: chainguard-images/alpine-base
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.6
  critical: false
  value: refs/heads/main
```

Getting and decoding the base64 is relatively straightforward `yq '.[].value | @base64d'`

I've tried many combinations of yq syntax but haven't figured this out.
The closest I've gotten is doing:

```yaml
export pathEnv=".[].value"
export valueEnv=".[].value|@base64d"

yq eval 'eval(strenv(pathEnv)) = strenv(valueEnv)'
```

But that gets me

```yaml
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.1
  critical: false
  value: .[].value|@base64d
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.2
  critical: false
  value: .[].value|@base64d

... (truncated)
```

It seems like wrapping the value replacement would work..
`yq eval 'eval(strenv(pathEnv)) = eval(strenv(valueEnv))'`

but that gets `Error: unexpected EOF`

I've tried using `sub()` in various ways but no luck..

All the examples I've seen of string replacement / substitution are for when you have just a *string* to use as replacement.
This seems a bit more complex because the replacement has to refer to a previous value in yq's pipeline somehow, that's then run through `@base64d`.

Perhaps it's possible using multiple yaml files?

What would be even better is if there was another yaml file mapping the `id` to it's name,
e.g.

```yaml
oidcIssuer: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.1
githubWorkflowTrigger: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.2
```

and have yq add them, something like:

```yaml
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.1
  named_oid: oidcIssuer
  critical: false
  value: https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com
- id: 1.3.6.1.4.1.57264.1.2
  named_oid: githubWorkflowTrigger
  critical: false
  value: schedule
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple, use the `|=` operator, which updates back the value to then node being operated, i.e.

```bash
yq '.[].value |= @base64d' yaml

# or alternatively

yq 'map(.value |= @base64d)' yaml
```

Note: If you are using yq version 4.18.1 or beyond, [the eval flag `e` is no longer needed](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1) as it has been made the default action.

Comment: I'm quite relieved it was just that easy! I somehow had the impression that @base64d needed to have something directly piped to it (rather than using the `|=`) Thank you!

Comment: Is the latter part of my question possible? Reading in another yaml file and using the key: value map to append to the array based on the matched `id` ?

Comment: @4x0v7 Please ask a separate question for the 2nd requirement. The SO guidelines recommend asking one unique question per post